# Push notification on iOS devices

Tags: ios, push-notification

I’m able to send and receive the push notification…In the push notification i will be sending some json encoded data…

Once my device receives the push notification,then if the user taps on the notification banner device can get the json data received by the push notification.…But what if user clears the notification banner,how can the iOS device receive the json data?…Any suggestion guys?…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `content-available` flag to 1 and iOS will call your app's delegate.

Answer (score 1):

There are just 2 ways to get push notification details, when application is not working. First one is not very reliable since it will provide you latest push notification only. Second one, you can't really use if you want banner and you want to notify user. Third one is just an alternate way to get latest updates from server.

1. Get details of last push notification in application Launch method :

> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
> NSDictionary *dicAPNS = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
> ```

2. Use silent Push notification, where user wont get any notification but you will be able to get notified. This is done by sending "content-available:1" in APNS Payload.
3. Call an server call to check if you have any update. So you can grab data from server what you might have received in missed push notification.

Answer (score 0):

I think iOS push notification fully depends on user's wish.I think the another web service needs to load all the content of data in push notification, if push notification is disabled or deleted by user.